# Quarkus panache unidirectional OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa, orm, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I want to implement a simple uni-directional one-to-many association. I have tried the below setup. But when I fetch the `Tenant` entity, I always see `null` for the `subscriptions` field.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
public class Tenant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String tenantKey;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="tenantKey")
    private Set<Subscription> subscriptions;

    public Set<Subscription> getSubscriptions() {
        return subscriptions;
    }

    public void setSubscriptions(Set<Subscription> subscriptions) {
        this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }
}
```

and below is the Subscription entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Subscription {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String tenantKey;
    private String serviceName;
}
```

Below is my repository class which I fetch the `Tenant` object

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TenantRepository implements PanacheRepository<Tenant> {

    public Uni<Tenant> findByTenantKey(String tenantKey) {
        return find("tenantKey= ?1", tenantKey).firstResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `Subscription.tenantKey` with a `Tenant` object and problem should gone. You are using an ORM, so use it's capabilities.

Comment: In that case, it will become a **bi-directional** relationship. I only want one-way relationship with these 2 entities.

Comment: Then remove the Subscription.tenantKey property outright. Your issue is you have JPA trying to set the tenantKey foriegn key column through the Tenant.subscription relationships, but you also have a Subscription.tenantKey property you are likely leaving set to null. Use one or the other. Alternative to removing it, you can make it read only by mapping it as updatable=false, insertable=false, but it'll likely be out of synch with the values when it changes.

Comment: PS what exactly do you wish tenantKey in your join column to reference? JPA mandates that relationships involve foreign keys that point to IDs. The setup you have means there is a Subscription."TENANTKEY" foreign key that points to the Tenant."ID" column - but you also seem to have a Tenant.tenantKey property (and db column). Did you mean to try to link the two up somehow, or is tenantKey a natural ID you might be using instead of the ID property?